# Behaviour of ReadableByteChannel.read()

Tags: java

Does read() return -1 if EOF is reached during the read operation, or on the subsequent call? The Java docs aren't entirely clear on this and neither is the book I'm reading.

The following code from the book is reading a file with three different types of values repeating, a double, a string of varying length and a binary long. The buffer is supposed to fill at some random place in the middle of any of the values, and the code will handle it. What I don't understand is if the -1 is returned **during** the read operation, the last values won't get output in the prinf statment.

```
    try(ReadableByteChannel inCh = Files.newByteChannel(file)) {
```

`ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(256);
        buf.position(buf.limit());
        int strLength = 0;
        byte[] strChars = null;

        while(true) {
            if(buf.remaining() < 8) {
                if(inCh.read(buf.compact()) == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                buf.flip();
            }
            strLength = (int)buf.getDouble();

            if (buf.remaining() < 2*strLength) {
                if(inCh.read(buf.compact()) == -1) {
                    System.err.println("EOF found while reading the prime string.");
                    break;
                }
                buf.flip();
            }
            strChars = new byte[2*strLength];
            buf.get(strChars);

            if(buf.remaining() <8) {
                if(inCh.read(buf.compact()) == -1) {
                    System.err.println("EOF found reading the binary prime value.");
                    break;
                }
                buf.flip();
            }
            System.out.printf("String length: %3s String: %-12s Binary Value: %3d%n", 
                                strLength, ByteBuffer.wrap(strChars).asCharBuffer(), buf.getLong());
        }
        System.out.println("\n EOF Reached.");`

Comment: if -1 was returned on the last valid read, you wouldn't know how much data you read...  seems like the answer is pretty self-evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make a simple test to understand how it works, like this

```
    ReadableByteChannel in = Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get("1.txt"));
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    System.out.println(in.read(b));
    System.out.println(in.read(b));
```

1.txt contains 1 byte, the test prints

```
1
-1
```